# onViewCreated with compatibility library

Tags: android, android-fragments, roboguice

In an Android application I have a fragment implemented that overrides [onViewCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to set up some OnClickListeners once the view is there.

This all works fine when I implement. However as soon as I add the compatibility library v4 r3 it seems that the method is not called at all.

For now I am migrating my setup into onResume but that is really not ideal. So here are my questions:

- Is this a bug in the compatibility library?
- Is there a better workaround?

After some more digging and trying different things I got this stacktrace, which lets me believe it is indeed a bug in the compatibility library.

```
10-07 14:25:11.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onViewCreated
        at roboguice.fragment.RoboFragment.onViewCreated(RoboFragment.java:18)
```

But even more weirdly. Looking at the compatibility library source that method is actually there but it is empty.

Comment: why don't you set the click listeners in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: because that is too early.. I am using roboguice and the injection needs to happen first. Come to think of it.. I might be able to do that.

Comment: Nope.. the injection happens in RoboFragment in onViewCreated and that is never called..

Comment: ouch. I guess you will need to issue a bug :(

Comment: Although the compat lib is not claiming support for onViewCreated. 

Can't you set up listeners in onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much back and forth and debugging I found the problem. It turns out I was using an old version of the compatibility library in my project. I have now updated my project and things work fine. For reference the needed change is to the compatibility library dependency in the maven pom file to be like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r3</version>
        </dependency>
```

with the library deployed to your Maven repo with the Maven Android SDK Deployer. I have also [updated the roboguice wiki](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20) and the [linked gist on my github account](https://gist.github.com/1259514).

Comment: See http://www.simpligility.com/2012/01/android-compatibility-library-following-lint/ for details on how to avoid needing to use the Maven Android SDK Deployer

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with a much newer compat revision, r10. It is not a very big problem, because I can easily bind / do stuff elsewhere, but still...

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. It _is_ a problem, because injecting the views right after injecting the non-view members in a custom implementation does not work.