# Android DialogFragment onViewCreated not called

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment

I am using android compatibility library (v4 revision 8). In the custom DialogFragment the overrided method onViewCreated is not getting called.For eg.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    private String mMessage;
    public MyDialogFragment(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreateDialog");
        setRetainInstance(true); 
        //....do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onViewCreated");
        //...do something
    }
}
```

onViewCreated is not getting logged.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: According to latest documentation once you override `onCreateDialog`, `onCreateView` won't be called same as `onViewCreated` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 32):

This is how I make sure onViewCreated is called in kotlin:

```
class MyDialog: DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var dialogView: View

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null)
        val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context!!)
                .setView(dialogView)
                .create()

        return dialog
    }

    // Need to return the view here or onViewCreated won't be called by DialogFragment, sigh
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return dialogView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Yay it's now called!
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        dialogView = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works flawlessly and makes it very easy to add flow collectors to `onViewCreated`! Minor change I made: since I use view binding, I don't need the additional val, I can just return `binding.root` in `onCreateView`

Comment: "dialogView" is non-null type can not be set to null in onDestroyView. BTW, this line of code seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: didnt work for me.. but using view binding with this technique just work.. i dont know why

Answer (score 26):

Well, the docs for onViewCreated  state "Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has returned".

DialogFragment uses onCreateDialog and not onCreateView, so onViewCreated is not fired.  (Would be my working theory, I haven't dived into the android source to confirm).

Comment: my problem is something like this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692713/onviewcreated-with-compatibility-library but the solution is'nt working

Comment: `onCreateView` is fired when building a DialogFragment, even when also using `onCreateDialog`.

Still, `onViewCreated` is not fired when building a DialogFragment. Odd behavior.

Comment: dialogfragment use onCreateView when super.onCreateDialog is returned.

Comment: I'm just curious why it is so hard to override the onViewCreated() for DialogFragment and throw a RuntimeException so developers know this method is not a part of Dialog (who extends Fragment)...

Comment: onViewCreated() is called in some fragments and for some other fragments it is not. Strange behavior.

Answer (score 15):

You can see what's happening from the source code:

First, since you don't override `onCreateView()` your fragment's view will be null. This can be seen from the [source code of `Fragment`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java) -- the default returns `null`:

```
// android.support.v4.app.Fragment.java
@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}
```

Second, since you're view is null the `FragmentManager` will not call `onViewCreated()`. From the [source code of `FragmentManager`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java):

```
// android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.java
if (f.mView != null) {
    f.mInnerView = f.mView;
    // ... 

    // only called if the fragments view is not null!
    f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
} else {
    f.mInnerView = null;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

From my testing, `onViewCreated` isn't called if onCreateView returns null, which is the default behavior, so if you're not using onCreateView but manually calling `setContentView` in `onCreateDialog`, you can manually call `onViewCreated` from `onCreateDialog`:

```
@Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    // ... do stuff....
    onViewCreated(d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content), savedInstanceState);
    return d;
}
```

In this case, make sure the root element in `my_dialog.xml` has `android:id="@+id/dialog_content"`

Comment: The only problem with this approach is if you're embeddeding the `DialogFragment`; in this case, `onViewCreated` would be called twice.

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc ([Selecting Between Dialog or Embedding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#Lifecycle)) and having it tested by myself, you can override OnCreateView, inflate it with your custom layout and return it. OnViewCreated will be launched

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
           //do whatever        
           return view; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that onCreateDialog will be called before onCreateView (DialogFragment documentation) and onCreateView will be called before onActivityCreated (Fragment documentation.
Therefore this would be the flow of calls:

```
onCreate
onCreateDialog
onCreateView
onActivityCreated
```

So do what you would do in OnViewCreated in onActivityCreated and you should be set.