# Gravity not working on DialogFragment for API < 14 (Gingerbread)

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm using the following code inside my `DialogFragment.onCreateView()` to set its gravity on top:

```
Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

This works perfectly on newer Android API versions but not on phones/emulators using Gingerbread (API 9 or 10). I also tried to use the following code on `onViewCreated()` without success:

```
View v = getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
getActivity().getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(v, lp);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
lp.y = -200;
lp.x= -200;
getActivity().getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(v, lp);
```

change the value of `lp.x` and `lp.y` as per your requirment

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry. But it was a good workaround to try. Also you made me see by debugging it that `onViewCreated()` is actually not called at all on a `DialogFragment`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594992/android-dialogfragment-onviewcreated-not-called