# Custom dialog not working with 'setOnClickListener' Android studio

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I have a bit of weird situation - I have a made a custom dialog that opens when a button from the activity is clicked. The custom dialog contains a close button that when clicked closes the dialog and returns user to the activity. When I run the code as it is (shown below), instead of launching the custom dialog, it goes to the main activity (I think either reopens the app or somehow creates a imaginary intent for the main activity). However, when I remove/comment the code for the close button - highlighted as // === this code, everything works fine (the custom dialog opens) but the close button doesn't function. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
    // Global variable
    Button openDialog;

    // ======
    openDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
    openDialog.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog cusomDialog = new Dialog(sellActivity.this);
            cusomDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);


            // === This code
            final Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        cusomDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
            // === This code

            cusomDialog.show();


        }
    });
```

Can someone please shed some light on this, as I am really confused.

Comment: Why downvote, have I done something wrong?

Comment: also you can follow this link https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Sorry, just got back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your View of `Dialog` inside `Dialog`:

Replace this:

```
final Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
```

With this:

```
final Button close = (Button) cusomDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
```

Answer (score 3):

At First, You should pass `cusomDialog` View Object  .

Secondly , **Dialog** Create and call method wrong .

```
   final Button close = (Button)cusomDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cusomDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
```

**Same problem**

```
openDialog = (Button)cusomDialog.findViewById(R.id.opendialog); //Rectified
```

You should read **[Custom Dialog](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88)** for more information .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inflate the layout and get the view and set the view in your custom dialog.

```
final Dialog cusomDialog = new Dialog(sellActivity.this);
View view = LayoutInflater.fromContext(sellActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.customdialog,false);
cusomDialog.setContentView(view);
Button close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close);
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use `DataBinding` write a callback in XML:

   ```
   android:onClick="@{_ -> viewModel.onClickAction()}"
   ```
2. If you use `ViewBinding` make sure `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` are called. See [Android DialogFragment onViewCreated not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594992/android-dialogfragment-onviewcreated-not-called).

   ```
   private lateinit var binding: YourDialogBinding

   override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
       binding = YourDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       // Create usual or custom dialog
       val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).setView(binding.root)
       return builder.create()
   }

   // Need to return the view here or onViewCreated won't be called by DialogFragment
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
       return binding.root
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       with(binding) {
           ...
   ```